# How to make clear get rid of the options menu icon?

Tags: android, menu

I looked on the android menu item and saw that clear() will "Remove all existing items from the menu, leaving it empty as if it had just been created." this works fine for me but the options menu icon is still there. Shouldn't the icon also disappear if the menu is empty?(i don't get a reason for still having it) Is there a way to make the icon disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the overflow menu item invisible in the xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:visible="false"/>
```

Or remove it at onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(false);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.addAction);
item.setVisible(false)

ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(YourAtivity.this)
```

On API < 11 use

```
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() method
```